# End iterator at a certain index

Tags: java, iterator

I'm currently writing a code and want to end my iterator at a certain index and I'm not able to figure it out.' This is my code but doesn't work.

```
    for(int i = 0; i< stop && iterator.hasNext(); i++){ 
        iterator.next();
        if(i == stop){ 
            break; 
        }
        return iterator;
    }
    return iterator;
```

Comment: `i< stop` will cause the loop to terminate when `i == stop ` so `if (i == stop){ ` will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove return iterator from inside the loop and your code will work fine. Right now, it is returning from your function on the loop's first iteration itself, i.e. when i = 0.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your code, there are a couple of things to note.  First of all, it will always return with i == 0.
You first time through the loop if i > 0 and it has next, you grab next and return iterator.  Otherwise the loop doesn't run and you return iterator.  As a note, the if can never be true because you will not run the loop in that case.

The code as written is equivalent to:

```
if ((i < stop) && iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next();
} 
return iterator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to break when you reach the position you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> xs = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E","F");
    Iterator<String> iter = xs.iterator();
    offsetIter(iter,3);

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String string = (String) iter.next();
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(string);
    }

}

public static <T> void offsetIter(Iterator<T> iter , int moveAt){
    int i = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if(i<moveAt){
            iter.next();
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Will result in:

```
 D E F
```

No need to return an iterator since iterator are mutable by principle.

Comment: but i want it to end at a certain point , like BCD and it stops if i said the index 4

Comment: Why not using a sublist?

Comment: what is that ? i know i need to end the iterator